# Host Twitter @anywhere JS file locally?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I'm using the Twitter @anywhere tweet box on my website, and I am wondering if I can host the anywhere.js file locally. As of now, I have found nothing that says I can't but also couldn't get it to work. I believe this is partly to do because it requires an ID in the url of the script.

Here's the documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome

Comment: "couldn't get it to work" - what exactly didn't work? Did you receive any error messages? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well simply including the code on my page resulted in the "Provide App ID" error. Normally, the url would look something like `<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=YOUR_API_KEY&v=1">`, so I don't think it would exactly work without calling it from Twitter's servers..